# Postman getting could get response error while sending response from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postman

I am creating API in Laravel and I am trying to get response in `postman`, but I am not getting response instead I am receiving "could not get any response" in `postman`.

Below is the code I am using controller:-

```
    public function get_states(Request $request){

    $get_states = DB::table('states')->get();

    return response()->json($get_states);

    return view('frontend.pmjkyppa.pmjkyppa_getstates',compact('get_states'));
}
```

And below is the code I am using in routes `web.php` file:-

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/pmjkyppa_home','pmjkyppa\HomeController@get_states');
```

[This is what I am getting in Postman (image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW1dc.jpg)

Comment: Your route is `/abc_home` but in postman you are firing a request to `/pmjkyppa_home`.

Comment: @Remul Oh! I have edited the code above. Now, you can get a clear picture. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you are using self-signed certificates on your server. 
Postman will prevent the connection to non-valid certificates.

You can disable that default behavior in `Settings>General` by turning off `SSL certificate verification`